# centre text in a div which is inside a td

Tags: html, text, html-table

I have the following:

```
<td rowspan="3"; class="outer"; color="green"><div class"inner"></div></td>
```

CSS:

```
.in{
text-align:center;
-webkit-border-radius:8em;
font-size:25px;
height:120px;
width:120px;
vertical-align:middle;
}

td{
text-align:center;
padding:0px;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
```

I am trying to produce a circle inside a div which is inside the td. I dynamically (ajax) add text (a number) to the div. So essentially I want a Circle with a number in the centre. The problem is that the text is always at the top of the circle and not in the centre.

Help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you provide us with a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `line-height:120px;` to your `.in` class

Comment: Super, worked brilliantly :D. Will mark as correct in 5 minutes. Thanks.